# Port Forwarding without hosting server

Tags: server, port, portforwarding

I just want to know if I can forward port 80 or 8080 or 21 on my router just to check if those ports are open to public. I don't have a server running on my PC though. I'm sure it's possible if a server is running and configured.

Comment: What is the aim? You want to make the webserver running on your private network available to the world?

Sure that's possible! You need to open a hole in the firewall for port 80, and configure NAT (network address translation). 
Google is your friend!

Comment: Kind of. Is it mandatory to host a server and keep it running for the public to see the ports open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very detailed link on how to do it , but i guess it is also depends on the router you've got  .

http://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html